# Advantage of using experiments in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

Many of TensorFlow's example applications create `Experiment`s and run one of the `Experiment`'s methods by calling `tf.contrib.data.learn_runner.run`. It looks like an `Experiment` is essentially a wrapper for an `Estimator`.

The code needed to create and run an `Experiment` looks more complex than the code needed to create, train, and evaluate an `Estimator`. I'm sure there's an advantage to using `Experiment`s, but I can't figure out what it is. Could someone fill me in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`tf.contrib.learn.Experiment`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) is a high-level API for distributed training. Here's from its doc:

> Experiment is a class containing all information needed to train a
>   model.
>
> After an experiment is created (by passing an Estimator and inputs for
>   training and evaluation), an Experiment instance knows how to invoke
>   training and eval loops in a sensible fashion for **distributed
>   training**.

Just like [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) (and the derived classes) is a high-level API that hides matrix multiplications, saving checkpoints and so on, `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` tries to hide the boilerplate you'd need to do for [distributed computation](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), namely `tf.train.ClusterSpec`, `tf.train.Server`, jobs, tasks, etc.

You can train and evaluate the `tf.estimator.Estimator` on a single machine without an `Experiment`. See the examples in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators).